# Is there an ASP equivalent of JSP's SkipPageException?

Tags: asp-classic

Subject says it all. In JSP you can throw a SkipPageException to abandon any further processing of the page, and the container catches it and ignores it. Is there an equivalent in (classic) ASP to skip the rest of a page after a validation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Response.End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524629%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method causes the Web server to stop processing the script and return the current result. The remaining contents of the file are not processed.